pip install | How to install private project from the local file system when using requirements.txt?
I'm trying to figure out how to properly use python3.8 -m pip install to install the requirements from requirements.txt AND simultaneously install certain packages from the local file system instead of from the repo. We have a few different private repos that we may need to work on simultaneously for larger changes.
I have found that I could do this as two separate commands. First python3.8 -m pip install -r requirements.txt --index-url https://private/repo/dependency/simple and then python3.8 -m pip install path/to/dependency. But I would like to combine these into one command if possible. This would avoid the need to generate and manage access tokens as part of the index url for each developer.

pip allows you to specify multiple packages just fine.
pip install path/to/local/package1 \
    path/to/another/package2 \
    -r requirements.txt

If path/to/local/package1 overrides a package which is also mentioned in requirements.txt, Pip will prefer the one earlier on the command line, and then just conclude that the requirement is already met once it finds it again in requirements.txt

The problem is that the additional dependency is - at least currently - in the requirements.txt. If I simply preprend it as you have done here - it still goes out to the repo to get it when processing the requirements document. If I don't include the --index-url parameter then it fails to install the package. And I want it to be present in the requirements document; I just want to override where its pulling from on occassion.

That is not my experience. If I pass in an --index-url then the index will be downloaded, but a local package specified explicitly with its disk path will take precedence over an uninstalled package in the index. If the package was already installed for other reasons, that could explain what you're seeing.

Hmmm. Is there a way to validate from the pip commandline where a given installed package was downloaded from? I'm taking over a project from an ex-colleague, but I haven't done much with Python :P

Nevermind - I was able to confirm that this approach works for me :)

I don't think pip records where a package came from. If you have logs from the event, they should include this information.

I think you can try directly specifying your path in your requirements.txt
like this:
# Packages
package1==X.0.0
package2==X.0.0

# Local Packages 
/path/to/local/dependency1


I'd prefer not to modify the requirements.txt if possible, but a good fallback method

Maybe you can create a new requirements.txt and run it in the same line:
In powershell:
cat requirements.txt > myRequirements.txt
echo path/to/dependency >> myRequirements.txt
python3.8 -m pip install -r myRequirements.txt

In most Unix shells, something like
printf '%s\n' \
    '-r requirements.txt' \
    'path/to/dependency' >myRequirements.txt
pip install -r myRequirements.txt

If you insist on making a one-liner, you can replace each backslashed newline with nothing, and each remaining newline with a semicolon character ;

The basic idea is fine but you have several errors in the details. Try printf '%s\n' '-r requirements.txt' 'path/to/local' >myRequirements.txt

no there are no errors in the code

It's pwsh if you're in doubt

This will produce a single line which isn't valid requirements.txt format. The .\  is an error on any non-Windows platform, and completely unnecessary anyway.

yes, you're right about the  .
I modify it

It's still creating a file with only one line.

No,  it's incredible to say that. Open a powershell and type echo one two > test.txt Now cat test.txt. you'll see 2 lines

okay actually you're right it's quite different in a classic bash it's only one line.

"classic bash", and ash, and dash, and ksh, and zsh, and basically everything else except powershell. Windows users are a minority here; you can't assume everyone has powershell at all.

and ? I'm on pwsh and I've made it clear from the start

No, your answer does not mention Powershell at all.

please you replied to the comment not to the main reply, where I clearly mention being under pwsh. Anyway I'll be careful to be more explicit next time I want to help someone, this was my first stack contribution. In any case, a great day to you

You can [edit] your answers, so improvements don't need to wait until next time. Specifying "in powershell:" before the existing code segment would be good. Adding a separate "in other shells:" section would be even better.

I will do it thanks
